# Can the progressive form serve as a repetition tool?

Tags: grammar

For example : 'The train comes in five minutes.' - 'What did you say?' - 'That the train is coming in five minutes.'
Can the progressive aspect is used as a repetition tool like here : 'Comes' is repeated as 'coming'.
What do you think of my thinking?

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes be helpful for a repetition of the same information to use slightly different wording. You have given one example, but the two sentences you used could equally well have been reversed. Or the second could have been replaced with "it is due in five minutes" or "it is five minutes away". The slight difference in expression can sometimes make it easier for the listener to understand. I don't believe there is any significance in which came first, or in different shades of meaning for the two sentences in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

"The train is coming in five minutes" is a natural way to express a future event that will happen as a direct result of the present state.  The simple present is not used here.  The simple present can be used for talking about future events that are fixed.  "The train arrives at 16:00" But with relative time, "in five minutes" you should use present continuous.

So the tense used is "The train is coming" in both the first sentence and the repeat.  There is no need to change the verb form when you repeat something.

You *might* make changes to simplify or clarify when you repeat.

> The 7:42 from Euston will arrive at platform 6 at 7:57.
>
> What did you say?
>
> I said our train is coming in five minutes. And we need to go to platform 6!

Comment: I thought a schedule (according to traditional rules) was the present simple? - Anyway, the English works often in this way. The exemple I've given to you is a real one.

Comment: I can say: I leave tomorrow at five in the morning -I can also say: I'm leaving tomorrow at five, without much if any difference.

Comment: I've clarified.  The issue, as I see it, is the use of the short relative time "in five minutes".  The verb also makes a difference.  "The train arrives in five minutes" is more acceptable than "The train comes in five minutes".  However, you should use the present continuous here throughout (or some other future tense: going to, or will) There is no need to change form for the repeat.

Comment: @ManuelDelpierre as James says, you can use simple present to talk about fixed times (**at** 5am) but you don't tend to use it with a short relative time (**in** five minutes).

Comment: The other reason to use "is coming", is that the arrival of the train is a result of where it is now, rather than a plan on a timetable.

Comment: I've read it in studying linguistics, it is a tool you can use (if you want), it is "anaphoric". It is a sort of connivence with the person you're speaking with. Let's not forget we are free to use different ways of speaking, writing, etc. if it is grammatical.